# Помогите с FOR LOOP :как сохранить ввод различных имён и фамилий и затем их гдето использовать

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Qty_Of_Musicians_With_Details {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int numberOfStudents = 0;
        //Variables
        String memberLastName = null;   
        String memberInstrument = null; 
        String memberFirstName = null;  
        int qtyOfMember;
        System.out.println("input number of members");
        //my scanner
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        //read and store user input
        qtyOfMember = userInput.nextInt();
        //Using FOR LOOP
        for(int i =1;i<=qtyOfMember;i++){
            //ask for member Name
            System.out.println("enter member full name");
            //read and store firstname
            member_FirstName= userInput.next();
            //read and store lastname
            member_LastName = userInput.next();

            //Ask for input member instrument
            System.out.println("member instrument");
            //Read and store member instrument
            member_Instrument=userInput.next();
        }       
        userInput.close();
    }

}
```

> May be the best way is to use nested For Loop?

Comment: Непонял! почему -1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не объявили переменные, в которые пытаетесь записать данные.

Вообще вы каждый раз перезаписываете переменные с данными пользователя так, что в конце будет доступно только последнее введённое имя. Предлагаю значения хранить в массиве.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Variables
    String[] member_LastName;
    String[] member_Instrument;
    String[] member_FirstName;
    int qtyOfMember;
    System.out.println("Input number of members");
    //my scanner
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    //read and store user input
    qtyOfMember = userInput.nextInt();
    if(qtyOfMember>0) {
        member_LastName = new String[qtyOfMember];
        member_Instrument = new String[qtyOfMember];
        member_FirstName = new String[qtyOfMember];
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Number of members must be greater than 0");
        return;
    }
    //Using FOR LOOP
    for (int i = 0; i < qtyOfMember; i++) {
        //ask for member Name
        System.out.println("Enter member full name");
        //read and store firstname
        member_FirstName[i] = userInput.next();
        //read and store lastname
        member_LastName[i] = userInput.next();

        //Ask for input member instrument
        System.out.println("member instrument");
        //Read and store member instrument
        member_Instrument[i] = userInput.next();
    }
    userInput.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < qtyOfMember; i++) {
        System.out.println("Member fullname: " + member_FirstName[i] + " " + member_LastName[i]);
        System.out.println("Member instrument: " + member_Instrument[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше завести класс с тремя полями и один массив.

Comment: @zRrr, согласен. Но, как мне кажется, ТС совсем новичок. И было бы не очень хорошо на этом этапе показать ему использование класса. Но это только моё субъективное мнение. Если не согласны, то добавьте ответ с классом - будет разнообразие. Тем более, что статистика Ru.SO показывает, что в среднем на один вопрос попадается всего один ответ. А это не хорошо.

Comment: бы обсолютно правы,я ещё не волшебник,я только учусь,нам задали проект вот сижу и ломаю голову,кстати ваш код работает без отказно,но можноли избежать использования 'Arrays'.т.к. мы этого ещё не проходили,в данном случае ето идеальный вариант,но указ такой: пользоваться тем ,что изучали на лекциях.если что в четверг и задам этот вопрос препадователю.Огромное Спасибо

Comment: @KonstantinF, если так, то указывайте в теле вопроса то, что изучали.